# File not found in intermediate folder on module : Project Build failed with error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

When I am building my project From Build> Rebuild Project, it fails with the follwing error.

[image]

Above error occurs for both the modules that i use im my project.

Also when i try to generate signed APK, it says APK generated successfully but there is no APK folder generated in outputs.

Suggest me the changes to be done to get rid of this error.

EDIT 1: Below is my build.gradle for main module of project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.washkart.activities"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("washkart.jks")
            storePassword System.getenv("KSTOREPWD")
            keyAlias "wk"
            keyPassword System.getenv("KEYPWD")
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
//    compile files('libs/PGSDK_v1.0.1.jar')
//    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile project(':acra-acra-4.8.1')
//    compile project(':acra')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
//configurations {
//    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
//}
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And below is the build.gradleof the module for which it could not find the file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'src/main/proguard/proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the contents of the "build.gradle" files?

Comment: @AndroidGuy : i have updated my question with build.gradle code.

Comment: The only thing I could find is that there might be a bug in Android Studio (https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter/issues/145).  What version of AS are you using?

Comment: I have Android Studio v2.3.2